# What is the best way to provide source to Nextjs' Image?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I am working on a website (Nextjs) that has a huge amount of images. So in order to have better performance, Image optimization is essential. I checked and saw that the Image component of nextjs makes many qualities and sizes from images in srcset. Also, my CDN provides query params to get images of specific quality and size. I think the best way is to make webp images in CDN and use that with the Image component of Next.js. But if the user browser doesn't support webp what would do Image component? Could it automatically convert it to jpg?
Is it better to use the image optimization of the Nextjs Image component or provide loader prop to it and use CDN optimization?

Comment: `next/image`'s default loader automatically detects the browser's supported image formats. See [`next/image` Acceptable Formats](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#acceptable-formats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next/image component. It has the best image optimization tool. It can optimized your local or CDN images also. I can optimized images by reducing size 20-60% without loosing image quality?

On the other if you have another formated image like jpg, png, svg then you can use [next-optimized-images](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images). This is the same as next/image component..